# Tkinter: Making a button panel contained in a class

Tags: python, class, oop, tkinter

I edited this post for clarity.  I would like to use a class to generate buttons from a list.  In the current script I am not using a list, I am just instantiating the class with the variable app1, and I get this in full screen:

[image: Present State]

If I uncomment list = [1,2,3], and I uncomment the def button(): function, I get a blank screen.  I suspect that using the "Place Buttons Grid" layout the buttons will land on top of each other, so I made a "Place Buttons Fill" layout to use for testing.

My ultimate goal is to generate a GUI that looks like this:

[image: Future]

But I know that I'm not referencing the class correctly.  How do I do it?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import font
from tkinter import *

class alertButton(object):

    def __init__(self, Canvas):

        self.canvas=Canvas
        myFont = font.Font(family='Helvetica', size=36, weight='bold')

        #Configure Buttons
        self.alertButton = Button(Canvas,text="Button 1",font=myFont, command=self.alertCycle, height=2, width=6)
        self.quitButton = Button(canvas,text="Quit",font=myFont, command=canvas.quit, height=2, width=6)

        #Place Buttons Pack
        #self.alertButton.pack(padx=25, ipady=15, side=LEFT)  # Pack from right to left
        #self.quitButton.pack(padx=25, ipady=15, side=LEFT)
        ##This quit button only exists to exit full screen.  Will remove later

        #Place Buttons Grid
        self.alertButton.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=20)
        self.quitButton.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=20)
        ##This quit button only exists to exit full screen.  Will remove later

    def alertCycle(self):
        print("Button Pressed")
        #print (alertButton.i)
        return

#list = [1,2,3]

#def button():
#    for i in range(list):
#        app[i]=alertButton(canvas)

root = tk.Tk()

root.title("Sensor GUI")
root.wm_attributes('-fullscreen', 'true')

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
canvas.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

app1 = alertButton(canvas)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you turn this into a [mcve] that we can actually run? If I remove all the obvious syntax errors and the reference to an image file in a directory I don't have, what I get is about 8 tall, narrow buttons laid out across the screen. The only reason there's not 20 (or 40) is that you can't fit that many buttons with 25 pixels of padding on each side in a canvas 700 pixels wide. So if you're not seeing the same thing, there's probably something different between your actual code and the code I got by trying to fix the non-running code you pasted.

Comment: Also, the `def button` line isn't commented, so I don't understand what you mean by uncommenting it. (If you comment it, you just get a `NameError` and the program exits…)

Comment: @abarnert I changed the code so that it works.  I think that my "grid" placement will cause new buttons to land on top of each other, so I left the "pack" placement section in and commented out.  I don't know how to reference the class to generate multiple buttons.  What were the syntax errors that I made, that you changed to generate multiple tall narrow buttons?  I can figure out button arrangement if I can get past that blocker.  Is the way that I'm using the commented button() function with list = [1,2,3] the right direction to take?  I would like to populate my buttons with a JSON later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably manage to make all your buttons inside a loop to simplify their creation a little bit.

- I made `AlertPanel` inherit from `tk.Frame`, which is the appropriate container to hold a collection of buttons; so in essence, `AlertPanel` is a `tk.Frame`. Using a `tk.Canvas` as in your posted code, although possible, did not seem right.
- `AlertPanel` is managing a collection of `tk.Buttons`, and a series of actions represented by methods activated by each button. `Button 1` and `2` are bound to `alert_cycle_1`, and `2`; the remaining to `alert_cycle_3_to_8`, which you can replace with the appropriate actions you want each button to trigger.
- `make_alert_buttons` is creating each button, with the proper text, attaches the proper action to it, and places the button at its place on the panel.
- The size and aspect of the buttons probably could use a bit of tweaking to look better; I did not touch your specifications.
- please note that removed the full screen because a glitch on my system seemed to prevent closing the window.

This gives something like this:

```
import tkinter as tk       # <-- avoid star imports
from tkinter import font

class AlertPanel(tk.Frame):   # <-- is a tk.Frame, and can be manipulated as such

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        super().__init__(self.master)

        self.myFont = font.Font(family='Helvetica', size=36, weight='bold')

        self.alert_actions = tuple([self.alert_cycle_1, self.alert_cycle_2] +\
                                   [self.alert_cycle_3_to_8] * 6 +\
                                   [self._quit])
        self.alert_buttons = []
        self.make_alert_buttons()
        self.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)   # <-- because self is a tk.Frame

    def make_alert_buttons(self):
        btn_idx = 0
        for row in range(3):
            for col in range(3):
                action = self.alert_actions[btn_idx]
                b_text = f"Button {btn_idx + 1}"
                if row == 2 and col == 2:
                    b_text = "Quit"
                b = tk.Button(self, 
                              text=b_text,
                              font=self.myFont, 
                              command=action, 
                              height=2, width=6)
                b.grid(row=row, column=col, padx=20)
                self.alert_buttons.append(b)
                btn_idx += 1
        self.alert_buttons = tuple(self.alert_buttons)


    def alert_cycle_1(self):
        print("Alert Button 1 Pressed")

    def alert_cycle_2(self):
        print("Alert Button 2 Pressed")

    def alert_cycle_3_to_8(self):   # <-- replace with appropriate action for  buttons 3 to 8
                                    #     and update self.alert_actions accordingly
        print("Alert Button 3 to 8 Pressed")

    def _quit(self):
        self.master.destroy()


root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Sensor GUI")
# root.wm_attributes('-fullscreen', 'true')  # <-- untested
app1 = AlertPanel(root)
root.mainloop()
```

[Edit]:  As a second thought, naming the class `AlertButtonPanel` is maybe a better idea

Comment: Thank you for your very complete answer!  This definitely accomplishes what I set out to learn about.  I wanted to use tk.canvas because you can paint the background with canvas.  The script that I'm adding to currently uses an LED to indicate connectivity to my server, Red = bad Green = good.  My thought was to use the background as a quick visual indicator of connectivity, but I think I can probably use green and red label elements in tk.frame instead.  Thank you very much!

Comment: Cool, glad I could help

Comment: Should my alert button panel be external to the class?  I'm starting to think that the class object should just describe the buttons and their actions.  I'm not going to instantiate multiple panels, only buttons.  I'm self-teaching Python, and I'm doing this as an exercise to correctly understand classes.

Comment: You can define a `class App(tk.Frame)` (that inherits from Frame) that contains an `AlertPanel ` Frame for your buttons. You can probably use it directly, with only alterations needed to attach the correct actions to your buttons, and some cosmetic changes to the aspect of the buttons.

Comment: No, I mean, I understand the script that you sent (or I think I do).  But, why is the frame included in the class?  I don't want to instantiate multiple frames, just multiple buttons.

Comment: Frame is a very common and useful container for a collection of widgets - it makes a lot of sense to group your buttons in a Frame.

Comment: I think I understand...In my original script I defined canvas before I instantiated alertButton(canvas).  Then I instantiated a Canvas widget in the class.  I thought that in doing so I had created a background canvas before instantiating alertButton(). Canvas cannot be a container. Likewise, Frame is the first element in the script that you built because it can actually function as a container.